What is the purpose of tmpfs mounts under /run/credentials?
I haven't seen these tmpfs /run/credentials ... listed mounts in my df output before.
What's it about
:> df -h
Filesystem                     Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs  1.0M     0  1.0M   0% /run/credentials/systemd-udev-load-credentials.service
tmpfs  1.0M     0  1.0M   0% /run/credentials/systemd-network-generator.service
tmpfs  1.0M     0  1.0M   0% /run/credentials/systemd-journald.service
tmpfs  1.0M     0  1.0M   0% /run/credentials/systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev-early.service
tmpfs  1.0M     0  1.0M   0% /run/credentials/systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
tmpfs  1.0M     0  1.0M   0% /run/credentials/systemd-sysctl.service
tmpfs  1.0M     0  1.0M   0% /run/credentials/systemd-networkd.service
tmpfs  1.0M     0  1.0M   0% /run/credentials/systemd-vconsole-setup.service
tmpfs  1.0M     0  1.0M   0% /run/credentials/systemd-tmpfiles-


Those look like systemd credentials, which are a way of exposing sensitive information to systemd services:

Credentials are limited-size binary or textual objects that may be passed to unit processes. They are primarily used for passing cryptographic keys (both public and private) or certificates, user account information or identity information from host to services. The data is accessible from the unit's processes via the file system, at a read-only location that (if possible and permitted) is backed by non-swappable memory. The data is only accessible to the user associated with the unit, via the User=/DynamicUser= settings (as well as the superuser). When available, the location of credentials is exported as the $CREDENTIALS_DIRECTORY environment variable to the unit's processes.
...
In order to reference the path a credential may be read from within a ExecStart= command line use "${CREDENTIALS_DIRECTORY}/mycred", e.g. "ExecStart=cat ${CREDENTIALS_DIRECTORY}/mycred". In order to reference the path a credential may be read from within a Environment= line use "%d/mycred", e.g. "Environment=MYCREDPATH=%d/mycred". For system services the path may also be referenced as "/run/credentials/UNITNAME" in cases where no interpolation is possible, e.g. configuration files of software that does not yet support credentials natively. $CREDENTIALS_DIRECTORY is considered the primary interface to look for credentials, though, since it also works for user services.


I have four arch installations and this is the only one with these mounts. What is different about this installation?

I don't know enough about your Arch installations to answer that question. I guess I would start by looking to see if they are running the same version of systemd.
